# How to remove nanosecond from file

Tags: text-processing

How can I remove nanosecond from every line in a file.
data looks like
filename is **test.csv**

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 15:05:52:016469121,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 15:05:52:016469121,1.13.0-0007
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed 's/:[[:digit:]]*,/,/' file
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 15:05:52,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 15:05:52,1.13.0-0007
```

it will replace the last colon, following digits, and final comma with just the comma.

Comment: Thanks RudiC, it worked and this looks more good what I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' -vOFS=',' '{sub(/:[0-9]{9}$/, "", $2); print}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1 2018-08-17 15:05:52 1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2 2018-08-17 15:05:52 1.13.0-0007
```

### Explanation

- `awk -F',' -vOFS=',' '{foo}' input.txt`: use `awk` with the field separator (and output field separator) `,`, running commands `foo`, on file `input.txt`.
- `sub(/:[0-9]{9}$/, "", $2);`: for the second field `$2`, replace the regular expression `:[0-9]{9}$` (i.e. nine digits in a row at the end of the field) with nothing.
- `print`: print the new line

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is removing the comma(,) between time and name

Comment: @SyedRizvi Fixed